# What's the best way to do UJS in rails when you have a re-usable widget?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials, ujs

In my current project I have a couple instances where I have a re-usable form that exists inside a rails partial. This form submits to a specific controller via ajax (:remote => true). The controller does some stuff and then returns back the appropriate js.erb to modify the page via javascript.

This works fine for when I have a single view. But the problem seems to happen when this re-usable partial exists on multiple views. In view 1 I might want to issue a completely different set of javascript commands then in view 2.

As a concrete example, say I have a comments controller that has the normal CRUD operations.

I now have partial called _comments_box.erb. This _comments_box.erb contains the ability  to submit a comment via a simple line:

```
- form_for comment, :url => post_comments_path(post), :remote => true do |f|
```

This submits to a comments_controller.rb create method which looks somethings like this:

```
def create
   ... do some stuff, like create a new comments model

   respond_to do |format|
      # will respond with create.js.erb
      format.js
   end

end
```

The create.js.erb in turn adds a comment to the view, perhaps doing a bunch of other updates to the DOM.

Say I render the _comments_box.erb within a view called post_summary.erb. Now I have another view, post_detail.erb that requires the same _comments_box.erb. However the post_detail.erb requires me to update completely different divs on the DOM in response to a new comment.

I need to create a different JS response for each instantiation. So I can either:

- Create an alternate controller method, say create_2. Pass in some parameter to the _comments_box.erb from post_detail.erb to the _comments_box.erb partial so it knows which controller method to fire. This will allow me to have a separate file _create_2.js.erb that will allow me to manipulate the post_detail.erb view independently.
- Forget about using js.erb altogether and just use plain old AJAX and get back JSON, and handle the javascript manipulation completely on the client-side.

It seems option 1 allows me to continue to use the UJS supported by Rails which is nice. But also means I probably will be adding a lot of duplicate code everywhere which is annoying. Is there a way for me to do this elegantly while continuing to use UJS?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid duplicated code in the comment creation (before the `respond_to` block) or in the different `js.erb` responses?

Comment: I want to allow for different js.erb responses depending on which start point I'm coming from. Basically I want to have a re-usable widget that allows for different UI changes depending on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not recommend using UJS for frontend apps: server shouldn't take care of client side business. I agree it's useful and clean but it lacks performance and thus should be kept for backend stuff (RJS will move into a gem, see here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default).

That said, back to the solutions you expose:

- 1) I think you won't need an extra controller, you'd just have to pass additional params in order to know from where to query came from. A `hidden_field` could do the trick. With this info, render the good `js.erb` file

  ```
  format.js { if condition
               render "create.js.erb"
              else
                render "create_2.js.erb"
              end
            }
  ```
- 2) I'd go for it and return json but you'll face the same problem: knowing from where the request comes from.

Comment: Thanks this is eventually the solution I ended up with. I added a hidden_field parameter "from" in the shared widget form. This allowed me to decide how to route back the correct erb. I will probably move away from using UJS over time as it seems a bit hacky. For option 2 the thought is I would return json and always allow the Javascript on the page to decide how to render the page. onready I would load the appropriate JS file and it would respond on ajax:success. I could use Backbone.js to better organize my javascript. It just seems wrong to replicate models/controllers in two places though

Comment: You could also use templates such as http://handlebars.strobeapp.com/ to clean up your js

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly the purpose of `Apotomo`: http://apotomo.de/

Here is it's own description:

> Apotomo is a true MVC widget framework
>   for Rails. Widgets are based on Cells
>   and provide reuseable view components.
>   Having bubbling events, they know when
>   and how to update themselves via AJAX!
>
> Working with Apotomo widgets almost
>   feels like developing GUI components –
>   in a Rails environment.

Have a try, it's great.

Comment: Thanks for this definitely looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution (than using a `hidden_field`) might be to check the `request.referer` in your controller action. This way you leverage the fact that each context has a unique URL, and don't have to explicitly specify another unique value when rendering your widget partial.